# File Upload PHP not successful

Tags: php, xml, http, file-upload

```
<?php

$target_path = "./" . 'data.xml';

if (move_uploaded_file('data.xml', $target_path)) {
    echo "The file  has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";

}
?>
```

The above PHP script doesn't seem to work. I tried sending a HTTP POST request to this link. I end up getting a BOOLEAN NO for the [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) and yes says there is an error.

I wonder what went wrong here.

Comment: What is the error? Do you have the write permission?

Comment: The echo output is what I referred to as error. I do have write permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
{
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} 
else
{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: Its a fixed file name. I dont want to change the file name to anything else but data.xml './' is to make sure the file is on the same folder as the upload.php

Comment: @DesperateLearner: Then make `$target_path` `'./data.xml'` — but you need this to find the temporary location of the uploaded file.